# google play real time multiplayer - .OnRoomSetupProgress intermittent error

Tags: android, google-play-services

Hi i'm currently testing a game using the google real time multi player apis.
During the start of a session i can log onto both test devices and test and run the game no issue. However as i'm doing lots of tests and tweaks I find that after a certain point in time trying to run new sessions of the game results in the progress for the realtime multiplayer listner being stuck at 20% on both devices. Or sometimes 20% and 73% on the other. [note these are clean installs, with no running sessions on the device] At this point i cannot get a room setup working. If i leave things as be for an hour or so (with no changes made). The apis start to work again and i can resume, again for a certain amount of time before the problem crops up again. I'm thinking the stuck on loading is possibly down to two causes. 1) from the previous game not exiting properly and the google apis think the previous game, users are still in session? or 2) there's some form of throttling on the amount of data allowed during a given period.
My testing is primarily using two noxplayer sessions, but also the same problem has happened using mobile devices and tablet
Has anyone had similar experience? Any suggestions as to how to resolve?

Many thanks

```
   #region RealTimeMultiplayerListener Implementation

void RealTimeMultiplayerListener.OnRoomSetupProgress(float percent)
{
    //        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.ShowWaitingRoomUI();

    msg.text="progress"+percent;
}
void RealTimeMultiplayerListener.OnRoomConnected(bool success)
{
    msg.text = "room connected";

SceneManager.LoadScene("MainGameScene");

}
```

Comment: That single line of code is not giving us a handle into what could be wrong with your code. If you provide more that might be a chance we could spot something.

Comment: Have a look also on how your question is written: one long paragraph will not attract that many readers. Try to break it up into several paragraphs, make some bullet points, ...

Comment: the onroomsetupProgress and onroomconnected fx do not have any real associated code. As stated the program works, but after running 4-5 times in a row in short succession the OnroomsetupProgress is stuck at 20% .. close and restart again an hour or so later and all is ok